# Sqlalchemy keyed tuple error with select distinct

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Keyed tuple objects returned by the same select distinct query, but created differently, are completely different, even though the result is the same.

Below is an example demonstrating this error:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import (sessionmaker, scoped_session,)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import (declarative_base,)

Base = declarative_base()
db_uri = 'sqlite:///test.db'
engine = sa.create_engine(db_uri, echo=True)
class Test(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    field2 = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


def main():
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    session = Session()
    session.add_all([Test(field2=i) for i in xrange(10)])
    session.add_all([Test(field2=i) for i in xrange(10)])
    session.commit()

    q1 = session.query(Test.field2).distinct().all()
    q2 = session.query(sa.distinct(Test.field2)).all()

    # print the results
    print 'Q1 results :' , ' -- ', [i for i in q1]
    print 'Q2 results :' , ' -- ', [i for i in q2]

    # print the keyed tuple dictionary 
    print 'Q1 as_dict :', [i._asdict() for i in q1]        
    print 'Q2 as_dict :', [i._asdict() for i in q2]
```

These 2 queries return exactly the same results as shown by the first pair of prints

However, The obj._as_dict() values are different; populated for the 1st query and empty for the second.

Is this normal? I'm I missing something ?

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that your `q2` looses the `name` of the field, whereas `_asdict()` returns values only for named columns. Adding `label` will solve it:

```
q2 = session.query(sa.distinct(Test.field2).label('field2')).all()
```